# Finding $P[|x-\mu|>1]$

Tags: probability

I have the following probability:

$$f(x)=2e^{-2x}\ ,  x\ge  0 $$
$$ \mu = 1/2$$

I thought that it's needed to do this: $$P[|x-\mu|>1] = 1- P[|x-\mu|<1]= 1-P[-1/2<x<3/2] =1- \int _{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}2e^{-2x}\:dx$$

Why does the  book tell me to do only:

$$\int _{0}^{\frac{3}{2}}2e^{-2x}\:dx$$

Why it's calculating the probability only from zero and not from -1/2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random variable with the given pdf does not have support on the negative real numbers. As such, $f(x)=0$ on $[-1/2,0)$ and the bounds of integration can be narrowed to start at $0$.

Comment: What would happend if we have |x| on the p.d.f. and the range is  |x|≥0, it's the same, to we evaluate from 0 onwards?

Comment: @Limanido It would not change anything since $x$ is non-negative anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is mostly correct. To see more clearly what is happening, you could see the random variable with support on all real numbers, but having the probability density
$$
g(x) := \left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
f(x) & \text{if} & x \geq 0, \\
0 & \text{if} & x < 0.
\end{array} \right.
$$
Then, when calculating $P[-1/2 < x < 3/2]$, you would calculate
$$
P[-1/2 < x < 3/2] = \int_{-1/2}^{3/2} g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^{3/2} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$